# Context-dependent Python object property?

Tags: python, methods, properties

I'd like to write a Python class with a property (I'll call it "position" here) that can be used in two different, context-dependent ways - kind of like what can be done in C with a union:

First way, it has sub-properties - I'll call them x and y:

```
my_object.position.x = 12
my_object.position.y = 13

print(my_object.position.x) # prints 12
```

Second way, it takes and delivers a tuple:

```
my_object.position = (12, 13)

print(my_object.position) # prints (12, 13)
```

I'm trying to do this only because sometimes it's more convenient to access as a tuple, other times as named sub-properties. The intent is that the tuple and the sub-properties represent the same information, so tuple[0] is the x property and tuple[1] is the y property, as in:

```
my_object.position = (12, 13)

my_object.position.y = 14
   
print(my_object.position) # prints (12, 14)
```

I know how to make it work either way (sub-properties or tuple), but not both.

(I'm aware that tuples are immutable - the data needn't be stored inside the object as a tuple.)

I also already know how to make the setter check for the type of input so it can (for example) accept either a tuple or None.

Is there a (reasonable) way to do this in Python? Is it a *bad idea*?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally reasonable thing to do in Python. If fact, it's already an established thing in Python.

It's called a namedtuple.

https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-namedtuple/

Comment: Thanks, but it's unclear to me how to make that work as a property (vs. an attribute). How would I write a setter than can handle either position as (x,y) or position.x position.y?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant that (I think) it could work.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys


class Pos:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 0:
            return self.x
        elif key == 1:
            return self.y
        raise IndexError("Index out of range")

    def __str__(self):
        return "({:}, {:})".format(self.x, self.y)


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._position = Pos()

    @property
    def position(self):
        return self._position

    @position.setter
    def position(self, value):
        self._position = Pos(*value)


def main(*argv):
    t = Test()
    print("pos:", t.position)
    t.position.y = 13
    print("pos:", t.position)
    t.position.x = 12
    print("pos.x:", t.position.x)
    t.position = (12, 13)
    print("pos:", t.position)
    t.position.y = 14
    print("pos:", t.position)
    x, y = t.position
    print(x, y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q067063954]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> pos: (0, 0)
> pos: (0, 13)
> pos.x: 12
> pos: (12, 13)
> pos: (12, 14)
> 12 14
>
> Done.
> ```